# Tkinter canvas in frame

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm creating a software that includes login page, start page, etc.
My login page class has a canvas with pictures ( I used tkinter designer for the design ), but it shows the canvas images in a frame,
How can I solve it?

```
class PageTwo(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.controller = controller

        self.canvas = Canvas(
            self,
            bg="#FFFFFF",
            height=595,
            width=975,
            bd=0,
            highlightthickness=0,
            relief="ridge",
        )
        self.canvas.place(x=0, y=0)
        image_image_1 = PhotoImage(file=relative_to_assets("image_1.png"))
        image_1 = self.canvas.create_image(110, 481.0, image=image_image_1)

        self.canvas.create_rectangle(
            487.0, 100.0, 488.0, 393.0, fill="#0093FF", outline=""
        )

        self.canvas.create_text(
            471.0,
            411.0,
            anchor="nw",
            text="Or:",
            fill="#000000",
            font=("LexendDeca Regular", 24 * -1),
        )

        self.canvas.pack()
```

I tried google it, didn't get any help related to my situation....

**EDIT**:

[This should be the start page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpBfq.png)

[And this is the login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZUCQ.png)

the picture from the canvas appear at the other frames

```
OUTPUT_PATH = Path(__file__).parent
ASSETS_PATH = OUTPUT_PATH / Path(r"assets\frame0")


class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.title_font = tkfont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=18, weight="bold", slant="italic")

        # the container is where we'll stack a bunch of frames
        # on top of each other, then the one we want visible
        # will be raised above the others
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        
        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):
            
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            # put all of the pages in the same location;
            # the one on the top of the stacking order
            # will be the one that is visible.
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        # self.frames["StartPage"] = StartPage(parent=container, controller=self)
        # self.frames["PageOne"] = PageOne(parent=container, controller=self)
        # self.frames["PageTwo"] = PageTwo(parent=container, controller=self)

        # self.frames["StartPage"].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        # self.frames["PageOne"].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        # self.frames["PageTwo"].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is the start page", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page One",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageOne"))
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page Two",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageTwo"))
        button1.pack()
        button2.pack()
        


class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 1", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        button.pack()


class PageTwo(tk.Frame):
    
    
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        
        self.controller = controller

        self.canvas = Canvas(
            self,
            bg = "#FFFFFF",
            height = 595,
            width = 975,
            bd = 0,
            highlightthickness = 0,
            relief = "ridge"
        )
        self.canvas.place(x = 0, y=0)
        image_image_1 = PhotoImage(
        file=relative_to_assets("image_1.png"))
        image_1 = self.canvas.create_image(
            110,
            481.0,
            image=image_image_1
        )

        self.canvas.create_rectangle(
        487.0,
        100.0,
        488.0,
        393.0,
        fill="#0093FF",
        outline="")

        self.canvas.create_text(
            471.0,
            411.0,
            anchor="nw",
            text="Or:",
            fill="#000000",
            font=("LexendDeca Regular", 24 * -1)
        )

        self.canvas.pack()

        self.canvas.create_text(
            406.0,
            24.0,
            anchor="nw",
            text="Chat AES",
            fill="#000000",
            font=("LexendDeca Regular", 36 * -1)
        )

        self.googlepicture = PhotoImage(
            file=relative_to_assets("button_1.png"))
        button_1 = Button(
            image=self.googlepicture,
            borderwidth=0,
            highlightthickness=0,
            relief="flat"
        )
        button_1.place(
            x=359.0,
            y=473.0,
            width=246.0,
            height=63.0
        )

        self.canvas.create_text(
            213.0,
            103.0,
            anchor="nw",
            text="Login:",
            fill="#000000",
            font=("LexendDeca Regular", 24 * -1)
        )

        self.canvas.create_text(
            696.0,
            103.0,
            anchor="nw",
            text="Sign Up:",
            fill="#000000",
            font=("LexendDeca Regular", 24 * -1)
        )

        self.canvas.create_text(
            571.0,
            155.0,
            anchor="nw",
            text="Email:",
            fill="#000000",
            font=("LexendDeca Regular", 16 * -1)
        )

        self.canvas.create_text(
            118.0,
            155.0,
            anchor="nw",
            text="Email:",
            fill="#000000",
            font=("LexendDeca Regular", 16 * -1)
        )

        self.canvas.create_text(
            571.0,
            216.0,
            anchor="nw",
            text="Username:",
            fill="#000000",
            font=("LexendDeca Regular", 16 * -1)
        )

        self.canvas.create_text(
            118.0,
            216.0,
            anchor="nw",
            text="Password:",
            fill="#000000",
            font=("LexendDeca Regular", 16 * -1)
        )

        self.canvas.create_text(
            569.0,
            272.0,
            anchor="nw",
            text="Password:",
            fill="#000000",
            font=("LexendDeca Regular", 16 * -1)
        )

        self.entry_image_1 = PhotoImage(
            file=relative_to_assets("entry_1.png"))
        self.entry_bg_1 = self.canvas.create_image(
            733.5,
            193.0,
            image=self.entry_image_1
        )
        entry_1 = Entry(
            bd=0,
            bg="#D9D9D9",
            fg="#000716",
            highlightthickness=0
        )
        entry_1.place(
            x=571.0,
            y=181.0,
            width=325.0,
            height=22.0
        )

        entry_image_2 = PhotoImage(
            file=relative_to_assets("entry_2.png"))
        entry_bg_2 = self.canvas.create_image(
            280.5,
            193.0,
            image=entry_image_2
        )
        entry_2 = Entry(
            bd=0,
            bg="#D9D9D9",
            fg="#000716",
            highlightthickness=0
        )
        entry_2.place(
            x=118.0,
            y=181.0,
            width=325.0,
            height=22.0
        )

        entry_image_3 = PhotoImage(
            file=relative_to_assets("entry_3.png"))
        entry_bg_3 = self.canvas.create_image(
            731.5,
            254.0,
            image=entry_image_3
        )
        entry_3 = Entry(
            bd=0,
            bg="#D9D9D9",
            fg="#000716",
            highlightthickness=0
        )
        entry_3.place(
            x=569.0,
            y=242.0,
            width=325.0,
            height=22.0
        )

        entry_image_4 = PhotoImage(
            file=relative_to_assets("entry_4.png"))
        entry_bg_4 = self.canvas.create_image(
            280.5,
            254.0,
            image=entry_image_4
        )
        entry_4 = Entry(
            bd=0,
            bg="#D9D9D9",
            fg="#000716",
            highlightthickness=0
        )
        entry_4.place(
            x=118.0,
            y=242.0,
            width=325.0,
            height=22.0
        )

        entry_image_5 = PhotoImage(
            file=relative_to_assets("entry_5.png"))
        entry_bg_5 = self.canvas.create_image(
            731.5,
            309.0,
            image=entry_image_5
        )
        entry_5 = Entry(
            bd=0,
            bg="#D9D9D9",
            fg="#000716",
            highlightthickness=0
        )
        entry_5.place(
            x=569.0,
            y=297.0,
            width=325.0,
            height=22.0
        )

        self.signuppic = PhotoImage(
            file=relative_to_assets("button_2.png"))
        button_2 = Button(
            image=self.signuppic,
            borderwidth=0,
            highlightthickness=0,
            command=lambda: print("button_2 clicked"),
            relief="flat"
        )
        button_2.place(
            x=661.0,
            y=350.5,
            width=167.0,
            height=37.0
        )

        self.loginpic = PhotoImage(
            file=relative_to_assets("button_3.png"))
        button_3 = Button(
            image=self.loginpic,
            borderwidth=0,
            highlightthickness=0,
            command=lambda: print("button_3 clicked"),
            relief="flat"
        )
        button_3.place(
            x=165.0,
            y=309.0,
            width=167.0,
            height=37.0
        )
        
        self.canvas.pack()

        

        
def relative_to_assets(path: str) -> Path:
        return ASSETS_PATH / Path(path)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: When you say "frame" do you mean to say that your images are shown with a border, or that they exist within a tkinter `Frame` widget? If it's the latter, that's because `PageTwo` inherits from `tk.Frame`, so the `self` acting as the parent of your `canvas` is a `Frame` object.

Comment: Frame widget, so what do you suggest? how to replace it? remove the self ?

Comment: First, there's nothing inherently wrong with this implementation as-is. Why exactly is having the `canvas` as the child of a `Frame` a problem? What are you trying to do that you *can't* do because of this? I just want to make sure this isn't an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) :)

Comment: How are you instantiating the `PageTwo` class? Can you add that code to your question? How you `pack()` that class object (or use it with any other geometry manager, for that matter) determines where it goes, and by extension where your `canvas` ends up

Comment: added the code of the entire file

Comment: from pathlib import Path

Comment: Comment out  line 217 to  223.  self.entry_image_1 = tk.PhotoImage(
            file="p1.png")
        self.entry_bg_1 = self.canvas.create_image(
            733.5,
            193.0,
            image=self.entry_image_1
        )

Comment: Didnt work, can you send the final 215 - 225 please?

Comment: You didn't specify the parent of those entry boxes and buttons, so they are put in the root window.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, I had to add `master` for every `widget`.
for the `Button`, `self`
for the `Entry`, `self.canvas`